# How to setup EFP Entity Framework Profiler in a Silverlight Application

Tags: entity-framework-4, silverlight-4.0, devforce

I can't add the reference to the HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll in the silverlight application because it is not a silverlight dll? I can add it to the web project but then how do I reference the dll in the silveright App.xaml Application_Startup call.

Answer (score 2):

See http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/efprof-first-look-profiling-devforce-sl.html

e.g. add the reference to your web project that hosts the silverlight control and then add the Initialize() method into your web project's global.asax Application_Start().

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is on the server only, you don't need to add any references in the silverlight project.  And HibernatingRhinos profiler is for NHibernate, not Entity Framework.

I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

> EFProf is an Entity Framework profiler from Hibernating Rhinos.

http://efprof.com/home